# How do I open a csv file in the root of my module directory?

Tags: module, csv, folder, paths

I've been writing a rather complicated module as of late. One of the steps I need to do is pre-populate one of the models with all of the data it needs to work right. This data is slowly replaced using a syncing system / rest calls from our database software, but it needs to be there initially so the end user doesn't think its 'all missing' before this sync happens.

I've been trying to use a csv file in my module directory.  For the life of me, I can't figure out the combination of factories and methods to get that folder. I can't assume its going to be in ANY particular place though, since this module will end up on a CDN hosted platform.

I've tried injecting

```
\Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\ReaderFactory
\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryListFactory
```

as well as direct php

```
__DIR__
dir()
dirname()
$_SERVER (ugh)
```

None of this can figure out

```
/var/www/app/code/mycompname/modulename/data.csv
```

while developing.. and

```
/var/www/vendor/mycompname/modulename/data.csv
```

when testing the composer distribution.

Any suggestions are welcome. I need to load the full path to use something like this....

```
$csv = file($pathThatWasFound);
```

EDIT: I read http://alanstorm.com/magento_base_directories <--- based on 1.x magento. I need 2.0 suggestions

EDIT: I may be bumping into constraints of **FILE** magic and xdebug (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924676/how-can-i-get-the-php-magic-constant-file-work-with-eclipse-and-pdt)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497441/generic-path-to-a-module-in-magento

I need to use the module namespace as well as the module name on getModuleDir()

```
$readerFactory->getModuleDir('','YourNameSpace_YourExtension')
```

This gives me the root path to my module.

My final exact copy of this thing is as follows:

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv',file($readerFactory->getModuleDir('','Stti_Healthday') . '/assignments.csv'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The [magento2 sample data](https://github.com/magento/magento2-sample-data) codebase has good examples of how this is done.

They define the `install` function in the model to populate the database.

This function is called inside the `<vendor_name>\<module_name>\Installer` class which is called inside the `<vendor_name>\<module_name>\InstallData` class.

Comment: I know how the installer works. Thanks though.  I guess I should have mentioned i'm running this function from InstallData.php

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are doing there are other options

https://github.com/DominicWatts/CsvUpload/blob/446ba3c80fc7f9136e7bdf6bda859c0e5d327ed0/view/adminhtml/templates/index/submit.phtml#L2

`<a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getViewFileUrl('Xigen_CsvUpload::template.csv'));?>" target="_blank"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__("CSV Template")); ?></a>`

So file path is

vendor/module/view/adminhtml|frontend/web/template.csv

Example

https://github.com/DominicWatts/CsvUpload/blob/master/view/adminhtml/web/template.csv